# Step-by-Step Bird Identification Guide

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

To start with, I should explain what I'm hoping to do, and this is a starting point to understand the complexities that I would need to cover for doing this 'Step-by-step guide to Bird Identification' part of a bigger project that I'm doing for my thesis project at university.

I'm hoping to develop a PHP with Ajax loading identification guide that would narrow down a bird in a location, by a few variables (there's 20 species) such as seasons (Autumn, Winter, Spring, Summer), country (England, Scotland, Wales & Ireland), then narrow down location to regions (north, west, east, south), beak-type (two types), body-type (sizes) and colours (multiple). The data can be pulled from a MySQL table.

To start with: I would like to know how this would be done with pre-defined questions after answering one question and once it has gone through all the questions, to display the possibilities of the species that is left in there.

I'm wondering what's the best way to start on a guide like this, and what would it be called? Here's a good example [National Geographic Bird Identifer Guide](http://animals.nationalgeographic.com/animals/birding/backyard-bird-identifier/), but it is done in Flash which is not what I'm aiming to do. But the principle is the same as I'm hoping to develop this to be light enough and quick to use on a mobile.

I look forward to hearing back from you on this problem.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: So you want us to do the project for you then?

Comment: My problem is I'm stuck on finding the right words on to find out how to do the process for this in PHP. I'm not really sure what's the right way of going about it when I start on this.

Comment: To answer a question like that, it is essential to understand the level of the audience's existing knowledge and skills.  Have you developed using these technologies before?  If so, what problems are you having translating that experience to this problem?  If not, with what technologies are you familiar?  If none, perhaps you need to break the project down into smaller tasks?  Basically, on *exactly what* are you stuck?

Comment: I have very basic PHP knowledge (php includes and so on). I can understand code, but the problem is the starting point of understanding the process and the right way of going about it.

Comment: @eggyal I would say I'm stuck on the process of elimination of variables as the questions gets answered and so on. I'm not sure how that would work when it goes down the list of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible ways of doing this, but how about this. You'll have a table with each row having one species of bird and each column a particular property, e.g. size, beak, region, etc. Each answer will add a condition to filter. E.g. "SELECT * FROM birds WHERE beak = 3 AND size = 4", the numbers will have whatever meanings you want to assign, or they could be strings or coordinates. With each question the number of possibilities shrinks.

You can either ask each question in any order, or you could do it like this. After each answer you evaluate each remaining question, choosing the question that when answered will reduce the numbers the most. Meaning there's no point asking about the colors of feathers if the all the remaining species have the same one.

This is a simplistic approach though, it might suit as a proof of concept though. The problem with it will be that people might have bad information or false beliefs and thus the answers will not be found. If you want a better algorithm you'll need to start from scratch and implement a simple AI algorithm. One which you'd teach the right answers by asking to identify a bird and it would take the best guess, and if it guesses right it will reinforce the data, and if not you'll have two possibilities, one it's an unknown bird, or it's a mistake. In one case it will add the species, in the other it will adjust the probabilities to allow identification. Something similar has been done here. http://www.20q.net/ But that will be more difficult and requires very patient training and a decent learning algorithm.

Comment: Thank for you setting me onto the right path of the process for this idea/project. I will be looking into algorithms for this.